# How do I change the footer links in Magento's iPhone theme?

Tags: theme, mobile, iphone

As you all know, Magento comes with a built-in iPhone theme for implementing a mobile theme to your ecommerce site. I understand for the most part on how to customize it. However, I cannot get the footer to change at all. The footer just has a link for "Contact Us" and that's it. I cannot find anywhere on how to customize the footer links to what I want. Does anyone have experience with this?

Feel free to browse to [www.shademountainarmory.com](http://www.shademountainarmory.com) on a mobile device and you'll see what I mean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I was looking for. Apparently, the iphone theme needs some modification in order to display footer links. It seems that it was left blank for some reason. I had to navigate to the file

> app/design/frontend/default/iphone/template/page/html/footer.phtml

I noticed that on line 28, it had this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml() ?>
```

I simply changed it to this:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('cms_footer_links') ?>
```

Problem solved! Whatever I have defined as the cms_footer_links in app/design/frontend/default/iphone/layout/cms.xml will dictate which CMS file to use for the footer links.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the template for Mage_Page_Block_Template_Links in which is the aforementioned Contact Us link by overriding this block in a child iphone theme in your project.